# Template class libraries

Tags: c++, templates

Template class header files contain both declarations as well as method implementations. So, is there any reason to put them in a library or a DLL vis-a-vis just distributing the header files? I mean any external program that wants to instantiate a template class must include that template class's header file and the template code will be compiled to become part of the program's own object module so that the any code in the library is unnecessary.
I can see the reason for putting them in a library if the template code calls into some special libraries or creates concrete classes by specializing any templates.
Am I missing something?
Thanks
Akwins.

Comment: It's completely OK to distribute header-only libraries.

Comment: if it is only a template class, a dll will never be created...

Comment: Not only will a dll never be created, if it's really all just headers, there will be no code to compile!

Answer (score 4):

If your headers are template-only, chances are they won't compile down to a binary DLL at all.

See Boost for an example of a C++ toolkit that has many header-only libraries (http://www.boost.org/)